Err: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
Description
I am facing the following crash when trying to checkout on a device with Android version API "VanillaIceCream" after setting the targetSdkVersion & compileSdkVersion 34.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: com.razorpay.newsampleapp, PID: 3019
java.lang.SecurityException: com.razorpay.newsampleapp: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specifi
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3242)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3226)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3209)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3151)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6064)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1880)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1820)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1808)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:757)
    at com.razorpay.CheckoutPresenterImpl.startSmsRetrieverForSavedCardsOTP(CheckoutPresenterImpl.java:887)
    at com.razorpay.CheckoutPresenterImpl.access$600(CheckoutPresenterImpl.java:59)
    at com.razorpay.G$_X_.onFinish(CheckoutPresenterImpl.java:866)
    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:142)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8674)

                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)

Razorpay SDK Version :
com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.20
Android OS Version :
Android version 14
What you did:
Updated targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion 34
What happened:
Facing an app crash while trying to checkout.
Error Snapshot
Steps To Reproduce

Set targetSdkVersion to 34 in the build.gradle(app) file.
Run your application on a device with Android version 14.
Proceed to the checkout. The Razorpay checkout page will open, but it will crash after 1-2 seconds, returning a checkout error.

Suggested solution:
As per the new update, either RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED must be specified when a receiver is not exclusively registered for system broadcasts. I encountered this issue with other broadcast receivers in my apps, and passing Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED as the second parameter in registerReceiver() helped resolve the problem. Applying a similar fix on Razorpay's end might also solve this issue.
Here is an example of my solution:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(AppConstants.MA_VIDEO_RECEIVER), Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
} else {
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(AppConstants.MA_VIDEO_RECEIVER));
}

I have tried searching for a solution to this error everywhere. To rule out any issues with my app, I even tried Razorpay's official sample app. I changed its targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 34, but I encountered the same issue. I have also opened an issue on Razorpay's GitHub, but haven't found a solution yet.

com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.20 is over two years old. Did you try 1.6.41, which was released earlier this month?

@CommonsWare Thank you for your response. It worked after changing the dependency to com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.41.
